# update value as selected value in EnumDropDownList

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enumdropdownlistfor

I created the `DropDownList` and `EnumDropDownList`.

Every option in `DropDownList` has an option with the same name on `EnumDropDownList`.

I take an option the user picked from `DropDownList` and I want to update `EnumDropDownList` that this specific option was selected by the user.

My `DropDownList` has an id `(id="ImageTypeDropDown")`
My `EnumDropDownList` has an `id ("id="FileTypeDropDown")`

How to fix the line:

```
document.getElementById('FileTypeDropDown2').options.find(wantedOption).Selected=true;
```

```
    <script>
      function adjustFitted() {            
            var e = document.getElementById('ImageTypeDropDown');
            var wantedOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;   // the option user chose - works well:)                         

            document.getElementById('FileTypeDropDown2').options.find(wantedOption).Selected=true;           

            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close.

```
function adjustFitted() {
        var targetVal = document.getElementById('ImageTypeDropDown').value;


        var targetDropDown = document.getElementById('FileTypeDropDown2');

        for (var i = 0; i < targetDropDown.options.length; i++) {
            if (targetDropDown.options[i].value == targetVal) {
                targetDropDown.options[i].selected = true;
            }
        }


        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work.  So I printed on screen: window.alert(document.getElementById('FileTypeDropDown2').value);  which showed 0 on screen.  can you tell me what's wrong please?

Comment: Please make sure that your options (which I assume are ListItems) have the 'Value' attribute set, e.g.

`<asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="a" />
<asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="b" />`

Comment: definition of dropdownlist is:  ` <div>
                            <br />
                            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.FittedEnumFileType, new { @id = "FileTypeDropDown2", @class = "form-control" })
                        </div> `

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize that you were working with ASP.NET MVC. I have edited my answer to a function that hopefully will work for you.

Comment: @NoahKo, did my answer fix your problem? If so, please mark my answer as correct so this thread doesn't stay open.

Comment: I still QA...I'll mark solution as correct after I finish QA. Thank you for your help!!